# weka stringToWordVector filter stringOptions

Tags: filter, weka

I'm trying to filter a dataset using weka's java API.  I've successfully filtered the attributes I want with a stringToWordVector filter in Weka's GUI but I can't seem to do the same in my java code.  I copied and pasted the auto-generated filtering parameters and posted them into my code but am continuing to get errors.  Currently, my code looks like this:

```
Instances newInsts = new Instances(this.instances);
StringToWordVector stringFilter = new StringToWordVector();
stringFilter.setOptions(
            weka.core.Utils.splitOptions("-R 1,2,3,4,8 -W 1000 
                                          -prune-rate -1.0 -N 0 -stemmer
                                           weka.core.stemmers.NullStemmer -M 1
                                          -tokenizer \"weka.core.tokenizers.WordTokenizer 
                                          -delimiters \" \\r\\n\\t.,;:\\\'\\\"()?!\""));
stringFilter.setInputFormat(newInsts);
newInsts = Filter.useFilter(newInsts, stringFilter);
```

But I keep getting this error in my eclipse console: No value given for -delimiters option.

(I added extra spacing for readability in the above code.  I suspect this has something to do with escaping characters/quotations marks...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually omit most of the options, as they are the defaults for StringToWordVector. The delimiters you're trying to pass are the default delimiters in the default tokenizer, [WordTokenizer](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/tokenizers/WordTokenizer.html), which are:

```
' \r\n\t.,;:'"()?!'
```

Comment: Right, but my question was really about why I was getting the "No value given for -delimiters option".  I did try to omit some of the options like you suggested which worked but then, after changing another piece of code, I got the original parameter string to work as well.  It looks like my problem was a different bug in my code that was tripping that error message for some reason.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. Perhaps include more code if you still want to track down the root cause of the error?