# How to create a string that includes a quoted string that includes a quoted string in Java?

Tags: java, string, machine-learning, weka, tokenize

I would like to put a string with options into Weka. Inside the options string is weka tokenizer string and inside the tokenizer string the delimiter option string. I am getting the error message "No value given for -delimiters option." How can I format the string?

Here is my code:

```
String[] options = weka.core.Utils.splitOptions("weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector "
            + "-R first-last -W 1000 -prune-rate -1.0 -N 0 -stemmer weka.core.stemmers.NullStemmer "
            + "-stopwords-handler weka.core.stopwords.Null -M 1 -tokenizer "
            + "\"weka.core.tokenizers.NGramTokenizer -max 5 -min 1 -delimiters \" \\r\\n\\t.,;:\\\'\\\"()?!\"");

StringToWordVector remove = new StringToWordVector();
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963210/weka-stringtowordvector-filter-stringoptions) did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

The error message you are getting says it cannot find any value after the `-delimeters` option.  The reason for this is that Weka is detecting that the string is immediately ending with a double quote after the `-delimeter` query parameter.  The root cause of this is a rogue quote mark which is appearing *before* the `weka.core.tokenizers.NGramTokenizer` term which belongs to the `-tokenizer` query parameter:

```
String[] options = weka.core.Utils.splitOptions("weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector "
        + "-R first-last -W 1000 -prune-rate -1.0 -N 0 -stemmer weka.core.stemmers.NullStemmer "
        + "-stopwords-handler weka.core.stopwords.Null -M 1 -tokenizer "
        + "\"weka.core.tokenizers.NGramTokenizer -max 5 -min 1 -delimiters \" \\r\\n\\t.,;:\\\'\\\"()?!\"");
           ^ rogue quotation mark.  Bad.
```

Change the string to the following and all should be fine:

```
String[] options =
    weka.core.Utils.splitOptions(
        "weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector "
      + "-R first-last -W 1000 -prune-rate -1.0 -N 0 "
      + "-stemmer weka.core.stemmers.NullStemmer "
      + "-stopwords-handler weka.core.stopwords.Null -M 1 "
      + "-tokenizer weka.core.tokenizers.NGramTokenizer -max 5 -min 1 "
      + "-delimiters \" \\r\\n\\t.,;:\\\'\\\"()?!\"");
```

Comment: Thanks, @Tim, @salc2, and @Scott. I am still working on it. Here is the string copied from the Weka GUI version that definitely works in there: `code`weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector -R first-last -W 1000 -prune-rate -1.0 -N 0 -stemmer weka.core.stemmers.NullStemmer -stopwords-handler weka.core.stopwords.Null -M 1 -tokenizer "weka.core.tokenizers.WordTokenizer -delimiters \" \\r\\n\\t.,;:\\\'\\\"()?!\"" The problem seems to be that there is a string following the tokenizer flag  that needs to include a string for the delimiter flag.

Comment: Thanks again everyone. Using the [OptionsToCode script](https://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code) I got it to work. "-R first-last -W 1000 -prune-rate -1.0 -N 0 -stemmer weka.core.stemmers.NullStemmer -stopwords-handler weka.core.stopwords.Null -M 1 -tokenizer \"weka.core.tokenizers.WordTokenizer -delimiters \\\" \\\\r\\\\n\\\\t.,;:\\\\\\\'\\\\\\\"()?!\\\"\""

Answer (score 1):

The content of the string you are passing to `splitOptions` is:

```
weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector -R first-last -W 1000 -prune-rate -1.0 -N 0 -stemmer weka.core.stemmers.NullStemmer -stopwords-handler weka.core.stopwords.Null -M 1 -tokenizer "weka.core.tokenizers.NGramTokenizer -max 5 -min 1 -delimiters " \\r\\n\\t.,;:\\\'\\"()?!"
```

I'm not sure what the argument to `-tokenizer` should be, but the string being passed to it has a `-delimiters` flag w/o any value, which is consistent w/ the error you reported.

Perhaps you meant to be passing this for `-tokenizer`:

```
"weka.core.tokenizers.NGramTokenizer -max 5 -min 1 -delimiters \" \\r\\n\\t.,;:\\\'\\"()?!\""
```

where the argument for `-delimiters` is a string.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe escaping quotes with `\`

```
String[] options = weka.core.Utils.splitOptions("\"weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector\"" + "\"-R first-last -W 1000 -prune-rate -1.0 -N 0 -stemmer weka.core.stemmers.NullStemmer\""+ "\"-stopwords-handler weka.core.stopwords.Null -M 1 -tokenizer\""+ "\"weka.core.tokenizers.NGramTokenizer -max 5 -min 1 -delimiters \" \\r\\n\\t.,;:\\\'\\\"()?!\"");
```